# Max7219 and Common Anode Displays, choosing the correct transistors

Tags: transistors, max7219

I've got some common *anode* 7 Segment displays that I want to use a Maxim 7219 IC to drive with. The [Max7219](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX7219-MAX7221.pdf) is designed for direct driving common *cathode* displays but Maxim do have an [app note](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/1/1196.html) that describes using the chip to drive higher current and/or voltage 7 segment displays as long as they are in a common *anode* configuration. In my case I want common anode, but at regular voltage/current levels.

The led's are fairly typical, 25mA max current, 3.3Vf, and I intend to drive everything from a 5V supply voltage.

I am not really sure what I should  be looking for in the transistors though? I went for these two

[2n3904 NPN Datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/KEC-Semicon-2N3904S-RTK-PS_C18536.pdf)

[AO3401A Fet Datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/Alpha-Omega-Semicon-AOS-AO3401A_C15127.pdf)

as they seem to be able to handle the relatively small currents and voltages involved, and seemed to be quite cheap. My proposed circuit is below.  Does this seem like a good choice?
[image: Propopsed circuit]

Comment: I'd go for a constant current-sink segment drive on your low side. You've easily got enough headroom for it and it isn't expensive. Something along [these lines](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/481317/38098).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did select a proper MOSFET and NPN transistor for your application. You selected a MOSFET that could handle maximum current through each seven segment display ( with good headroom) and voltage rating. You selected a proper NPN transistor which can handle current of each LED and with proper voltage ratings.  These transistors can work at 5V. The circuit also looks good.