# Boosting load current of voltage regulator

Tags: led, voltage-regulator, current-limiting

I'm trying to connect little 3v LEDs to a motorcycle's alternator and i want to regulate the voltage of it to 3 volts so the LEDs don't burn up
the alternator gives off 2.5 volts and over with 3 amps and over
i can't get my hands on a better regulator, and i have LF33CVs
how can i boost the possible current load? i know i can't connect them in parallel but the datasheet doesn't give a sample circuit
thanks

Comment: 2.5 volts sounds fine. Do you actually mean 12.5 volts? It's unclear why you want to boost the output current of a voltage regulator.

Comment: no its an old motorcycle the alternator gives 2.5 volts at ideal rpm and goes to over 4 volts at higher rpms

Comment: So you want to convert 2.5~4V to 3V for LEDs? LF33CV  is 3.3V output as long as input is sufficient

Comment: Do you want it to work even at low rpm and 2.5V input available for LF33CV?

Comment: i just want to limit the voltage over 3.2-3.3V to that amount, which is the limit of the LEDs

Comment: lower volatege than 3.3V isn't a problem actually

Comment: LF33CV  will not give output higher than 3.3V even if input is higher and will provide up to 500mA

Comment: Do you need more than 500mA?

Comment: yes i'm okay with 3.3V, i don't want higher voltage than that so i can keep the LEDs safe; i need to somehow boost the current it provides

Comment: the LF33CV can't keep up with the 3ish amp current running through it; that's the main problem

Comment: The full 3 amps from the alternator will not be going through the regulator.  The regulator only has to pass the current required by the LEDs.

Comment: Can i stop the LEDs from drawing too much current? Cause i already burned out 2 regulators

Comment: @AmirEbrahimnejad Yes. Just use a current-limiter circuit. You can build one with just two BJTs. The [design details are here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/481317/38098).

Comment: So if I'm having 8 LEDs is parallel, each drawing about 300mA, I'm good with a 3A regulator?

Comment: XY problem! Fix your existing electrical system instead of trying to invent a way around it.

Answer (score 0):

You may choose a higher current [LDO](http://www.shintron.com.tw/proimages/b8-1/LM3930X-R1.0.pdf) regulator:

[image: ldo3]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the current, it is the voltage.
A red led uses ~1V forward voltage at 10mA. Use a 180 Ohm resistor in serie.
Good look with your motorbike.