# Regulating voltage from an alternator

Tags: led, voltage-regulator, alternator

I asked a question about voltage regulators but didn't get a proper answer, so here's a new one.
So i have this motorcycle with an alternator.
The alternator gives out about 3 volts at idle speed, but as you add throttle, it goes up gradually to 4,5 volts
Now I'm using LEDs that work at 3 volts, so i want to regulate the output voltage (whatever it is, 3,3.2,3.5,4) to 3 volts.
I want to do that so the lights don't dim all the time (don't know if that's the right word, changing brightness) and of course don't burn out
Is there a circuit to do?
I'm quite new to electronics and don't have much technical knowledge.
Thanks

LEDs work best at 3-3.2V and each draw 300-320mA; I'm going to use 10 in front and 10 in the back
[image: 1W led]

Data sheet:
http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1636581.pdf

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113029/discussion-on-question-by-amir-ebrahimnejad-regulating-voltage-from-an-alternato).

Comment: You already posted this at [Boosting load current of voltage regulator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/521504/boosting-load-current-of-voltage-regulator) **DO NOT REPOST** instead use `edit`s to improve your *existing* question and make it something meaningfully answerable.

Answer (score 1):

The current voltage standard for motorcycle and car electrical systems is 12 V DC. It was 6V DC  in the early years.

The alternator would work as it should, only in tandem with the rectifier, regulator and battery. The battery is a must not only to store electrical energy but also to function as a filter capacitor. Without the battery, the voltage of the unfiltered output would naturally be lower than it should be. A defective rectifier / regulator could also cause a drop in the voltage.

The reason for the low voltage of 3 to 4.5 V could be attributed to the absence of the battery and problems in the rectifier and regulator.

It would not be worth expending time and effort to incorporate LED lights with a defective electrical system.