# LTspice - Simple, performant voltage limited current source?

Tags: ltspice, simulation

I'm a software engineer, so forgive me, my lack of proper vocabulary.
I've started building energy simulator in LTspice for thermal energy transfer between objects, based on thermal analogy to electric circuits.
I've done pretty much all I needed, using simple PWL based current sources and passive elements.

However, now I'd like to make a current source with feedback loop, i.e.
I want my PWL based current source to lower the current (or to be scaled down if you will), when temperature of energy sink goes above certain threshold.
In electronic terms I think that what I need is a voltage limited current source ? Yes I've tried to google it but since I've a rudimentary or no knowledge of active circuits, it's as if I was trying to google advanced programming staff, while not knowing any programming 
What is important, is speed of calculation. Currently I'm at 600ks-1Ms/s of simulation speed and since I have 240Ms  to simulate, it is quite important to maintain the speed . So, preferably a simply solution based on ideal transistors that are easy to simulate for LTspice would be perfect.

What I came up with, is for example

[image]

This circuit obviously does the job. However, when voltage on the Sink goes above 25V, simulation speed slows dramatically (from 500ks/s to 2ms/s). I'd assume that it is difficult to compute this circuit.
I've created couple another approximation of what I need but again at certain spots it slowed down to 2ms/s and it didn't seem to be able to go pass trough that simulation point.

I would appreciate if someone could help out with name of what I'm looking for or a simple diagram.

Edit1:
I've placed and connected a transistor with ideal model, on the circuit and simulation speed dropped to 10ks/s, so unless there are some model parameters that can be set to 0 or infinity that will speed it up, I guess the only option would be to create some approximation using passive components.

Comment: I don't know if [this link on EESE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/481317/38098) helps. But it may cover some helpful terminology, at least. It may also help in forming up something that will simulate fast, using realistic components. But it will not help at all in understanding what causes Spice simulations to slow down a lot.

Comment: I've placed a transistor o the schematic and applied default transistor model to it and it slows down do 10ks/s, so I guess that unless there is a trick to speed up transistor simulation by changing some of its model values to 0 or infinity, it is not an option.
Only passive elements

Comment: You probably used a concept instead of a real schematic, otherwise the voltage would end up in the negative MV or lower across the current source. At any rate, if it's a PWL, try using a voltage source feeding the noninverting input of a VCCS, whose inverting input takes the controlling voltage from the output (e.g. a feedback system).

Comment: What does "performant" mean in this context? Engineers prefer language that has actual meaning, including quantities and their values.

Comment: The problem with using a model of a real device like a diode or transistor means that the simulator is going to be solving exponentials and trying to match voltages via all the 'realistic' baggage. As your forte is software, you might consider doing something with the 'Behavioral Source' element in LTSpice, which is a V or I source block controlled by a pure equation you write, either to replace D1 and D2, or the current source + D2, or whatever. The equation can take current and voltage parameters from any components and nodes respectively on the circuit.

Comment: Might be a good idea to show exactly what you're simulating.  The screenshot you currently show will not run, so I assume it's just a mock schematic.  Show the real one or a simplified one which will actually run, including the `.model` statements for the diodes and the `.tran` command.  Also, learn what the G-source is.  It's explained within LTspice's built-in help, but cached here too:  https://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/G_Voltage_Dependent_Current_Source.htm

Comment: agree with Mr Kulov, G with the linear interpolation table= looks flexible with low compute overhead

Comment: @Bart Just to clarify, the circuit, as shown, won't work as you think it will. A current source has to generate the current *no matter the load*. There's a diode which, when reversed polarized, will have an Roff>1 MOhm. If the source has -1 A then the voltage across will be <-1 MV. If what you want are positive values only then use a voltage source driving a VCCS (G source) with `table(0,0,1k,1k)`. For `abs()` use `table(-1k,1k,0,0,1k,1k)`. Delete the diode and leave only the R||C. [Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNB9o.png). For feedback use output -> `-` input of the VCCS.

Comment: Why are you using a current source?