# Current limiter tight tolerance

Tags: circuit-analysis, current-source, current-limiting, inrush-current

Background:
The existing current limiter in the design has a relatively large tolerance primarily because of the component tolerance of the current limiter transistor.
[image]

Note; the temperature and voltage tolerance of the BC857 transistor needs to be considered. To address this, an NTC resistor R70 is used to reduce the temperature tolerance from 27% to 10%.

My goal is to create a current limiter circuit that ensures a minimum of 10mA output, With this design it would deliver 10-15mA due to tolerances.

Due to tolerance, it is needed for a new current limiter design that is more precise and exhibits less tolerance across a temperature range of -25 to 45 degrees Celsius.

Specifications for this new design include operating within the range of 10V to 23V, minimizing overshoot in current, reducing leakage, and minimizing voltage dropout. While the LT3092 has been identified as a potential solution and is currently being tested, it is considered relatively expensive. Therefore, any input or suggestions for alternative solutions are welcome.

Comment: You might start by looking [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/481317/330261) and then discuss what about the approach doesn't work for you.